# How to get a really tiny loan when self-employed?

Tags: credit, borrowing, microlending

I am newly self-employed and need a pinch of money to resolve some current loans. I need only 100 to 200 dollars on short notice -- has to be deposited to bank so a credit card cannot help.

I have no tax documents since I am newly working. I am an independent contractor and do not work directly for any persons who can be directly reached due to the nature of working online in specialized, anonymous platforms. Given that it is such a small risk I would assume it would be easy to loan a measly 100 bucks or even 200, but not having any luck.

Any ideas? Family is not an option and neither would be friends.

Comment: Have you tried peer to peer lending sites like Prosper?

Comment: Why are friends and family not an option? Why do you say it's a small risk? Unless someone is your friend, how would they differentiate you from a typical scammer asking for money?

Comment: Some credit cards do actually offer *money transfers*, transfers direct to a bank account. For a fee of course. And *most* (I believe) credit cards allow cash advances, for a fee. Withdraw cash from ATM using CC, deposit to bank account, done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a solicitation for money.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of options.

1. Use a credit card. You can usually get a cash advance on a credit card at a bank or ATM, and then deposit the cash to your bank account.
2. Get your bank to give you a loan, through some sort of line of credit or overdraft. This is usually too much hassle to go through for small amounts, but if this happens frequently it's worth doing.
3. Peer to peer lending sites.
4. Payday loan services. These will charge you extortionate fees and interest rates, and should be absolutely your last resort. Really, don't do this unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Pawnshop also comes to mind ...